# Performance issues if MapComponent state is updated

Tags: reactjs, performance, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am not sure if this is an issue of react-leaflet-markercluster, react-leaflet, leaflet, react, or my code.

I have a map with several thousand markers and I am using react-leaflet-markercluster for marker clustering. If I need to update a global state of `MapComponent`, there is 1-3 seconds delay when this change is reflected.

I created a [codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-worker-pvuhg) with 5000 markers and you can see there 2 use cases with performance issues:

1.) `MapComponent` is inside [react-reflex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reflex) element, that allows resizing panel and propagates new dimensions (width, height) to `MapComponent`. If width and height are changed, `mapRef.invalidateSize()` is called to update map dimensions. Resizing is extremely slow.

2.) If user clicks on `Marker`, global state selected is updated. It is a list of clicked marker ids. Map calls `fitBounds` method to focus on clicked marker and also marker icon is changed. There is around 1 second delay.

In my project, if I need to change a `MapComponent` state, it takes 2-3 seconds in dev mode when changes are reflected and it is just a single rerender of `MapComponent` and its elements (markers).

I took a look at Chrome performance [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhZL7.jpg) and it seems like most time is spent in internal React methods.

It is possible to fix this by preventing rerendering using `memo`, which is similar to `shouldComponentUpdate`, but it makes whole code base too complicated. `preferCanvas` option doesn't change anything. I am wondering what is a good way to fix these issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem I identified in your code is that you re-render the whole set of marker components. If you memoize the generation of those, you achieve a good performance boost; instead of running the `.map` in JSX, you can store all the components in a const; this way, the `.map` won't run on every render.

from this

```
...
   <MarkerClusterGroup>
     {markers.map((marker, i) => {
...
```

to something like this

```
  const markerComponents = React.useMemo(() => {
    return markers.map((marker) => {
      return (
        <MarkerContainer .../>
      );
    });
  }, [markers, onMarkerClick]);

  return (
    <>
      <MarkerClusterGroup>{markerComponents}</MarkerClusterGroup>
    </>
  );
```

The second refactor I tried is changing the way you select a marker. Instead of determining the selected prop from the selected array for each marker, I put a selected field on every marker object and update it when selecting a marker. Also, I add the position to the onClickHandler args to avoid looking for that in the markers array.

There are some other tweaks I don't explain here so please check my codesandbox version.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-andras-tfl67?file=/src/App.js